# Admin Access Unreachable with Addthis Facebook Like Button

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, admin

I am using Addthis Like button on my website http://www.bidicin.com which consists of just one page.  I can like the page without a problem and the like action can be seen both on my wall and my friends' news feed.  However I cannot see my website in my Activities and Interests section of my profile.  In addition to that I cannot see this website in my pages, so I cannot reach the admin page of this website.

When I use Facebook linter to check my meta tags I don't see any problems.  Currently I am usign the  meta tag, however I also used "fb:app_id" and it didn't work either.  I don't have any problems accessing the Facebook admin page of my website's blog http://blog.bidicin.com.  How can I access the Facebook admin page of my website.  Could you please assist me?

Comment: "However I cannot see my website in my Activities and Interests section of my profile. " I was unaware that this part of a user's profile can be changed via the facebook like plugin. I thought only facebook apps could get permissions to change that stuff, not just by clicking a like button. Can you share a link to the documentation of where it says it will change that part of the user profile?